# Propper package structure in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, namespaces, package

I've been looking for an answer here but it seems that all existing questions relate to a little bit different problem.
Anyway, I am writing an App that will surely grow very large so I decided to divide it in several logical submodules from the begining. Let's say it looks like this

```
package/
    | - __init__.py
    | - model/
    |       | - __init__.py
    |       | - nodes.py # containing Node() class
    |       | - connections.py # containing Edge() class
    |       | - ... # and so on
    | - view/
    |       | - __init__.py
    |       | - widgets.py
    |       | - ... # And so on with several modules here each containing a few classes
    | - controller/
    |       | - __init__.py
    |       | - main_controller.py
    |       | - ... # You get the idea
    | - main.py
```

Now, the import system within files:

```
# packages/__init__.py
import package.controller
import package.view
import package.model

# packages/model/__init__.py
from package.model.data import *
from package.model.connections import *
```

Then every module in the project would just `import package` at the begining, so it has access to the whole project. I don't want my code to become unreadable with long namespaces but still it should be clear what belongs to what and be separated. I will have classes named similarly (or same) in model and view submodules so I don't want to have any confusion or conflicts. Also, I want to use classes from all of the models with same logic. Like this, for example:

```
# random_file.py
import package

node = package.model.Node() # and not package.model.nodes.Node()
gui_node = package.view.nodes.GraphicNode()
```

All of this works, but when I try to make modules within same subpackage communicate like this:

```
# package/model/node.py
import package

class Node:
    edge = package.model.Edge()
```

I get `AttributeError: partially initialized module 'package' has no attribute 'model' (most likely due to a circular import)`

There must be a clean and consistent way to do this, but how should I organize my files and imports? Any hints and help is much appreciated.